Ubuntu showing nvidia error while booting
When Ubuntu the nvidia persistence erro shows, the nvidia persistence service is running fine.This happens after 2 days of usage
error in boot

Too little detail provided: So, what do you see when you try the suggested systemctl command?

Welcome to AskUbuntu. The error says to run systemctl status nvidia-persistenced Please edit your question and include the output from this command. Please copy and paste this information into your question. Thanks.

systemctl status nvidia-persistenced this command shows service running
